Hiding zero times in Excel
I work on a number of spreadsheets that do many complex calculations on times (minutes and seconds), and I want to hide the values where the result is zero.  However, sometimes the results are not exactly zero, so even with the sheet set to hide zero values, a zero might still show.
I know that one way to fix this is to surround the formula with =Round(t*86400,0)/86400 where 86400 is the number of seconds in a day and t is the formula returning a time result.  But for a spreadsheet that already has many intensive calculations (including some custom ones), that's a lot of extra work (for both me and the recalculation process).
Is there an easier way to hide times that are zero minutes and zero seconds, but may be returning a result that is, for example 3.46945E-18 (which is 3 ten-millionths of a second)?

Try this cell formatting hh:mm:ss;;;. This will hide 0 values.

No, that doesn't work.  You missed the point that the values are not actually zero.  See the second and last sentences of my question.

You can use IF like =IF(t<0.001,"",t)

@m-sarabi, Thanks for that.  True, that would be simpler than my formula above, but still not ideal (and per Black cat's answer, 0.001 is not sufficient; it needs to be 0.0000115, which is just under half a second).  But I also didn't mention that I need to handle negative times, so the IF would need to be something like=IF(and(t<0.0000115,t>-0.0000115),t,""), which is getting complex again.

Apply formatting like this:

Format cells ... -> Number -> Custom

type in the Type box
[<0,0000115]"",hh:mm:ss
this will conditional formatting the cell to empty string or hh:mm:ss format.

Thanks for that.  I don't want to show the hours, and I want minutes and seconds to be shown differently (02'41, for example), and I had to change the decimal point and separator to . and ; respectively for my locale, but you put me on the right track.  I also needed to handle negative times, and only want the seconds shown if there are any (which I handle with conditional formatting), but with the space left for them, so what I actually used was [<-0.0000115]-[m]_'_0_0;[>0.0000115][m]_'_0_0;"", but your answer was what got me there.
